# Counting rows in data.table, grouping by multiple columns, including "empty" groups

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like the following:

```
    ID      Date        Team    MonthFactor
1   2512    2015-04-24  Purple  2015-04
2   2512    2015-04-25  Purple  2015-04
3   2512    2015-04-26  Purple  2015-04
4   2512    2015-04-27  Purple  2015-04
```

I would like to get the number of rows grouped by both `Team` and `MonthFactor`, including when there are *no* rows from a given month, IE if purple team had no entries in the month of May but yellow did, the summarized table would look like:

```
    Team    MonthFactor N
1   Purple  2015-04     10
2   Purple  2015-05     0
3   Yellow  2015-04     5
4   Yellow  2015-05     7
```

Doing this would be trivial if I didn't need the "empty" groups, but I can't wrap my head around how to specify the groups that need to be evaluated when there might not be rows that contain a given monthFactor.

Comment: please provide example data that allows to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this could work

```
data.table(table(dt$Team,dt$MonthFactor))
```

Comment: So simple, and looks to be exactly what I need! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that by using a cross-join:

```
dat[, .N, .(Team, MonthFactor)
    ][CJ(Team, MonthFactor, unique = TRUE), on = c(Team = "V1", MonthFactor = "V2")
      ][is.na(N), N := 0][]
```

this gives:

```
     Team MonthFactor N
1: Purple     2015-04 2
2: Purple     2015-05 0
3: Yellow     2015-04 5
4: Yellow     2015-05 3
```

The advantage of this method is that it is easier to include other variables as well. Supposing that `ID` is just a numeric value, consider this example:

```
dat[, .(.N, sID = sum(ID)), .(Team, MonthFactor)
    ][CJ(Team, MonthFactor, unique = TRUE), on = c(Team = "V1", MonthFactor = "V2")
      ][is.na(N), `:=` (N = 0, sID = 0)][]
```

which gives:

```
     Team MonthFactor N   sID
1: Purple     2015-04 2  5024
2: Purple     2015-05 0     0
3: Yellow     2015-04 5 12560
4: Yellow     2015-05 3  7536
```

---

Used data:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L, 2512L), 
                      Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2015-04-24", "2015-04-25", "2015-04-26", "2015-04-27"), class = "factor"), 
                      Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Purple", "Yellow"), class = "factor"), 
                      MonthFactor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2015-04", "2015-05"), class = "factor")),
                 .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Team", "MonthFactor"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```